# Why is $\dim(W)=3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am teaching myself upper-division linear algebra for the moment, and I currently do not understand this example in my textbook.

This is from page 50 of Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel, and Spence - 4th edition.

> Let $W$ be defined by $$W=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)\in F^5 : a_1+a_3+a_5=0,a_2=a_4\}.$$ It is easily shown that $W$ is a subspace of $F^5$ having $$\{(-1,0,1,0,0),(-1,0,0,0,1),(0,1,0,1,0)\}$$ as a basis. Thus $\dim(W)=3$.

I understand that $\dim(W)=3$ because there are three elements listed in the basis of $W$. But how did the textbook come up with this basis, given the above definition of $W$?

Also, an even stupider question: what is $F^5$? I know that $F$ in my textbook is a field, and in linear algebra a field is typically seen as either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, although there are others or $F$ can even be treated generally.

Comment: usually in elementary courses either field of reals or complex numbers is consisered. $F^5$ simply meaning every vector is a 5 -tuple whose components are on $F$.hint for the main part or your question write down the conditions as a system of two equations and see what can be said.

Comment: $F$ is some field.  $F^5$ is the set of 5-tuples each of whose 5 components is an element of $F$.

Comment: So $F^5$ basically contains an ordered list of five elements in it? (e.g. $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5) \in F^5$?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we can rewrite the first relation as $a_1 = -a_3 - a_5$.  Given $\vec{a} \in W$, then
\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\
a_2\\
a_3\\
a_4\\
a_5\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-a_3 - a_5\\
a_2\\
a_3\\
a_2\\
a_5\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
a_2\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix} +
a_3\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
0\\
1\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix} +  
a_5\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix} \, .
\end{align*}

And, as mentioned in the comments, $F^5 = F \times \cdots \times F = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_5) : x_i \in F \text{ for } i = 1, \ldots 5\}$.